# Meaning of "There was a smell in the hall like the interior of a clock"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I stumbled upon this sentence (**There was a smell in the hall like the interior of a clock**) when I read one story and I still can't figure out its meaning.
Can somebody help?
Thanks.

Comment: It means literally what it says. The inside of a clock would have been enclosed for a long time and smell musty. So did the hall.

Comment: _You should always give the source of your quotation, please!_ I don't know whether the inside of a large clock such as a [longcase clock](https://www.dorsetantiqueclocks.co.uk/longcase-clocks/) has a distinctive smell.

Comment: I though it was an "unusual" image, but [checking Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like+the+interior+of+a+clock%22) it seems that this particular (metaphoric?) usage has appeared in print in many different contexts. Probably derives from various different "writers-to-be" who remember the strange musty smell that would waft out from a grandfather clock on its once-a-week opening and winding, when they were children.

Comment: @KateBunting, I don't know about longcase clocks in particular, but most antique clocks definitely do! It's the smell of the oil you use to lubricate the movement, old sewing machines have a similar smell.

Comment: This made me think of one of my favourite songs: _She makes me so unsure of myself
/Standing there but never ever talking sense 
/Just a visitor you see 
/So much wanting to be seen 
/She'd open up the doors and vaguely carry us away 
/It's the customary thing to say or do 
/To a disappointed proud man in his grief 
/And on Fridays she'd be there 
/But on Mondays not at all 
/Just casually appearing from the clock across the hall_

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mdewey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this does not go unanswered this collects some information from the comments.

I said

> It means literally what it says. The inside of a clock would have been enclosed for a long time and smell musty. So did the hall.

This was confirmed by, amongst others, Kate Bunting and BeginTheBeguine who pointed out the smell in antique clocks probably comes from the lubricant used. They are seldom opened so the smell builds up.